# How to get an access to webpage from external php file

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to create a simple register page. I made two separate files for HTML and PHP. So in post method I include this second file like this: `<form action="register.php"  method="post">`. The problem is after submitting registration I want to check all this columns and if are wrong, put some information about it. But everything opens in a new blank page. I want to maintain PHP and HTML in separate files. Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700"       
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"   
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<title> Rejestracja</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "imover">
    <nav><div id = "navcontainer"><ul>
        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Our projects</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul></div></nav>
    <div id = "socialscontainer"><div id = "fb"><a href = "#"><i class="fab 
fa-facebook-square"></i></a></div><div id = "tw"><a href = "#"><i class="fab 
fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
</div><div style = "clear: both;"></div>

    </div>
    <header><div id = "logocontainer"><h1>Register</h1></div></header>
    <div id = "container">
        <form action="register.php"  method="post">
            <h2>Username</h2><input type = "text" name = "username">
            <h2>Password</h2><input type = "password" name = "pass1">
            <h2>Confirm password</h2><input type = "password" name = "pass2">
            <h2>E-Mail</h2><input type = "text" name = "email">
            <br/><br/>
            <input type = "submit" id ="btn" value="Register now!">
        </form>
    </div>
            <span><a href = "logowanie.php">Do you have an account? Log in 
 now!</a></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And there's register.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass1'];
if($_POST['pass2'] !=$password) {header("Location: mistake.php"); exit();}
$hashed_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo $username;
?>
```

Comment: Show us what's going wrong in your code, we can't guess it.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Okay I just did

Comment: It opens a new blank window because u redirected to your .php file. Theres no html in it, i guess, so its empty ... But it should echo the username :)

Comment: How can I make it that this .php file will manage post method, but not be placed as a redirected website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to stay on the same website u need to delete the 'action'-attribute in the form tag and to use your php file, add
`<?php include ('register.php') ?>`
at the top of your html.

Maybe u will need to change the '.html' to a '.php' but thats not a problem, i hope.

Plus u may need to add sth like this:

```
  if ( isset($_POST['username'])){      
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['pass1'];
        if($_POST['pass2'] !=$password) {header("Location: mistake.php"); exit();}
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        echo $username;
    }
```

Otherwise it could crash because there are no values in $_POST then u enter the website the first time